# Symfony2 - Validation for form with multiple entities not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine, client-server

I have a Form for **Product** with relation *oneToMany* with entity **ProductLocale** and the user can add many **ProductLocale** as he want.

The rendered form in html seems correct but when I receive the POST array and perform `bind()` the server response this error:

```
"ERROR: This value should be of type Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale.
```

But I send two **ProductLocale** entities and validator doesn't recognize them.

It is obvious that the *POST* request contains a multi-dimensional array that contains the various entities **ProductLocale**, but the question is why

```
$form->bindRequest($request)
```

doesn't work correctly?

#### Edit #1:

## Product Entity

```
<?php

namespace Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Table(name="product")
*/

class Product
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     *@ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BrandOwner", cascade="persist") 
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale")
     */
    protected $productLocales;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductPic")
     */
    protected $productPic;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productLocales = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** 
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */ 
    public function createTimestamps()
    {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get creationDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set owner
     *
     * @param \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\BrandOwner $owner
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setOwner(\Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\BrandOwner $owner = null)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get owner
     *
     * @return \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\BrandOwner 
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }


    /**
     * Get ProductLocales
     *
     * @return \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale 
     */
    public function getProductLocales()
    {
        return $this->productLocales;
    }

    /**
     * Set ProductLocale
     *
     * @param \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale $productLocale
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setProductLocales(ArrayCollection $productLocales = null)
    {
        $this->productLocales = $productLocales;

        //return $this->productLocale;
    }

    /**
    * Add ProductLocale
    *
    * @param ProductLocale $productLocale
    */
    /*
    public function addProductLocale(ProductLocale $productLocale)
    {
        $this->productLocales[] = $productLocale;
    }

    public function removeProductLocale(ProductLocale $productLocale)
    {
        $this->productLocale->removeElement($productLocale);
    }*/

       /**
     * Get ProductPic
     *
     * @return \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductPic
     */
    public function getProductPic()
    {
        return $this->productPic;
    }

    /**
     * Set ProductPic
     *
     * @param \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductPic $productPic
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setProductPic(ProductPic $productPic = null)
    {
        $this->productPic = $productPic;
    }

    /**
    * Add ProductPic
    *
    * @param ProductPic $productPic
    */
    public function addProductPic(ProductPic $productPic)
   {
       $this->productPic[] = $productPic;
   }
}
```

## ProductLocale Entity

```
<?php

namespace Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Table(name="product_locale")
*/

class ProductLocale
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", cascade="persist") 
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     *@ORM\Column(name="market_nation", type="string")
     */
    private $marketNation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $link;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=9, scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /** 
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */ 

    /*
    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        if (!$this->product->contains($product)) {
            $this->product->add($product);
        }
    }
    */
    public function createTimestamps()
    {
        $this->creationDate = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set marketNation
     *
     * @param string $marketNation
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setMarketNation($marketNation)
    {
        $this->marketNation = $marketNation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get marketNation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMarketNation()
    {
        return $this->marketNation;
    }

    /**
     * Set link
     *
     * @param string $link
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setLink($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get link
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency
     *
     * @param string $currency
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * Set creationDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $creationDate
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setCreationDate($creationDate)
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get creationDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\Product $product
     * @return ProductLocale
     */
    public function setProduct(\Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\Product 
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the Product and ProductLocale entities and form types. we usually can't answer without them.

Comment: I'm still uncertain about this line: @Assert\Type(type="Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale"). But let's see your form types too, maybe you're missing something there.

Comment: i'm not sure if thats your issue but have a look at [@Assert\Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Yes @ihsan and @snyx, you're absolutely right, I removed this line: 
`@Assert\Type(type="Wearplay\WearBundle\Entity\ProductLocale` and everything worked perfectly.

I'm sorry for the trivial question but I'm pretty new in Symfony2.